# Open a File of a specific module Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I get somes module in Intellij. Let's assume that ProjectName is : ..One

Project

--> ModuleProjectNameOne
  --> src/main/MyMainClass

-->ModuleProjectNameTwo
 --> src/main/java

-->ModuleProjectNameThree 
     -->folder/pom.txt
     -->  src/main/MyMainClass

I wan to open the pom.txt

```
  File file= new File("pom.txt");
  if (file.exists()) {

            System.out.println("File");
  } else if (fr.isDirectory()) {

            System.out.println("Directory!");
  }
```

Here the root of the project

```
  System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath()); // shows C:\user...\ModuleProjectNameOne\.
```

How could i reach the specific file pomxt inside ModuleProjectNameThree ?

Comment: What do you mean by `How could i reach the specific file pomxt inside ModuleProjectNameThree?`

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution

```
File fr = new File("../ModuleProjectNameThree/folder/pom.txt");
```